# bash: checks 3 commands if they are installed

Tags: bash

I wanted to check if 3 commands are installed and if not show a warning message.

I tried that, but it didn't quite work out.
does anyone have an idea?

Code:

```
getCurl=`hash curl 2>/dev/null`
getWget=`hash wget 2>/dev/null`
getTar=`hash tar 2>/dev/null`

if ! [ "$getCurl" == "" ] ; [ "$getWget" == "" ] ; [ "$getTar" == "" ]; then
    echo "WARNING: curl, wget or tar not installed!"
fi
```

Comment: What do you mean by "didn't quite work out" - what happened and why was it wrong?

Comment: I think `which` would be better than `hash` here: `which curl`, `which wget`, `which tar`. `which` will return the path to the executable, or nothing if it's not installed (or not in the PATH variable)

Comment: `command -v`, if you want portability. And the `;`s ignore all but the last command.

Comment: @JNevill, `which` is an external command in bash, so it's much slower than asking the shell to do an internal lookup.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I always learn new things when you post. `command -v` was a new one for me. I'll definitely add that to my toolbox!

Comment: A less-portable but equally performant alternative is `type -P`, btw.

Comment: @JNevill in addition to the reasons Chrles Duffy mentioned, there are times `which` will be misleading.  See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85249/why-not-use-which-what-to-use-then, notably, `which` will only look for executables, so if someone had, here, created a function that did one of those commands instead of relying on the executable, `which` or `hash` would not give you the right idea of what was going to happen when you tried to execute the command

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One portable way to do this would be:

```
if ! { command -v curl && command -v wget && command -v tar; } >/dev/null 2>&1; then
  echo "One of curl, wget or tar is not installed!" >&2
fi
```

Why was the old approach broken?

- `foo ; bar` only returns the exit status of `bar`. Similarly, `! true; true` returns `true`, because the non-negated `true` is the last command in the sequence. In contrast to `;`, `&&` stops (short-circuits) at the first failure.
- `[ "$foo" == "bar" ]` is not portable, because [POSIX `test`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html) only guarantees `=`, not `==`, as a string comparison operation.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but with this script I have the same problem as with mine, if you only installed curl and tar but not wget the script does not work.
you don't get an error message.